# dynamic storage class on gcp kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set k8 cluster on centos7 spinned on gcp cloud. i created 3 masters and 2 worker nodes. installation and checks are fine. now i am trying to create dynamic storage class to use gcp disk, but somehow it goes in pending state and no error messages found. can anyone point me to correct doc or steps to make sure it works.

```
[root@master1 ~]# cat slowdisk.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
  zone: us-east1-b

[root@master1 ~]# cat pclaim-slow.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2G

[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pvc
NAME     STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
claim2   Pending                                                     5m58s

[root@master1 ~]# kubectl describe pvc
Name:          claim2
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"claim2","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"accessModes...
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:        <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the storage class name. The value storageClassName: standard  needs to be added on to PVC manifest file pclaim-slow.yaml.

Comment: i did try with adding that parameter but its same result. Is there any doc/step to setup this dynamic storage class ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the storageClassName in PVC yaml. Below is the update pvc.yaml. Check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#using-dynamic-provisioning) as well.

`kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce`
storageClassName: standard 
  `resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2G`

Comment: i have it in. i delete sc and pvc of past and created again. below is the config file [root@master1 02112020]# cat pclaim-fast.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: fast
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2G
[root@master1 02112020]# kubectl get sc
NAME   PROVISIONER            RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
fast   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   Delete          Immediate           false                  29m

Comment: @AdSaheba Can you please paste the output of `kubectl get pv` along with the events from the namespace/pvc?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of weird that you are not getting any error events from your `PersistenVolumeClaim`.

You can read [Provisioning regional Persistent Disks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/regional-pd), which says:

It's in Beta

> This is a Beta release of local PersistentVolumes. This feature is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and might be subject to backward-incompatible changes.

Also `pd-standard` type, which you have configured is supposed to be used for drives of at least 200Gi.

> **Note:** To use regional persistent disks of type  `pd-standard`, set the  `PersistentVolumeClaim.storage`  attribute to  `200Gi`  or higher. If you need a smaller persistent disk, use  `pd-ssd`  instead of  `pd-standard`.

You can read more regarding [Dynamic Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic).

If you encounter this error `PVC pending Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider` that means your cluster was not configured to use `GCE` as `Cloud Provider`. It can be fixed by adding `cloud-provider: gce` to the controller manager or just applying the `yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterConfiguration
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    cloud-provider: gce
    cloud-config: /etc/kubernetes/cloud
  extraVolumes:
  - name: cloud-config
    hostPath: /etc/kubernetes/cloud-config
    mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/cloud
    pathType: FileOrCreate
```

`kubeadm upgrade apply --config gce.yaml`

Let me know if that helps, if not I'll try to be more helpful.

Comment: i apply above file and it upgraded with gce as cloud provider. here is the output. [root@master1 ~]# kubectl get sc
NAME   PROVISIONER            RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
slow   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   Delete          Immediate           false                  6m3s
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pvc
NAME     STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
claim2   Pending                                      slow           4m47s

Comment: [root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pv
No resources found in default namespace.
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl describe pvc
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                  From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                 ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  92s (x9 over 5m13s)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "slow": cannot determine zones to provision volume in

Comment: is there any specific paramter in /etc/kubernetes/cloud-config ? i have added below content    [root@master1 ~]# cat  /etc/kubernetes/cloud-config
[Global]
project-id = "enterp-search"
multizone = true

Comment: i used both pd-standard and pd-ssd and both are showing same in pvc.      Warning  ProvisioningFailed  103s (x17 over 23m)  persistentvolume-controller  Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "slow": cannot determine zones to provision volume in

Comment: @AdSaheba, please edit the main question and put those additional information there.